# converting EDI 837I to XML format file using BizTalk server

Tags: xml, biztalk, data-conversion, edi, biztalk-2013

While i am converting  EDI 837I to XML format file using BizTalk server 2013 i am  getting the below error

```
An output message of the component "Unknown " in receive pipeline "Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.DefaultPipelines.EdiReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is suspended due to the following error: 
     Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error)
    22: Invalid Control Structure

Error: 2 (Miscellaneous error)
    1: Control Number in ISA and IEA do not match

Error: 3 (Miscellaneous error)
    21: Number Of included groups do not match.
 The sequence number of the suspended message is 1.
```

Comment: Please add some more info. The current error message is basically: "Some error occured"

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer HI, thanks for your response i updated exact error message could you please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 22: Invalid Control Structure
>
> 1: Control Number in ISA and IEA do not match

This means basically you are trying to process **invalid X12 EDI**.

The second message is very explicit and should be taken at face value.  The Control Numbers do not match between ISA and IEA.

It looks like someone tried to manually edit the EDI.  You can do that, but all the controls and counts need to be updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes manually changing the delimiters (maybe caused by opening in certain text editors) causes the above error. Make sure the following values in ISA and IEA do match.

[ISA and IEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBcai.png)